# C# onClick dynamic function name of a button

Tags: c#, uwp

So the problem is about naming buttons 'dynamically' in .cs file.

Normal way of creating button looks like this:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "AAA";
btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
btn.Content = "BBB";
btn.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
btn.Click += Btn_Click;
```

And for the function `Btn_Click` automatically created, it looks like this:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

However, now I would like to generate several buttons, and I hope that the name of function can be "dynamically" set from a string. Codes look like this:

```
for (int n=0;n<10;n++)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Name = "AAA_"+n.ToString();
    btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    btn.Content = "BBB_"+n.ToString();
    btn.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
    btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
    btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    string Btn_ClickTemp = "Btn_Click"+n.ToString();
    btn.Click += Btn_ClickTemp;
}
```

with function

```
private void Btn_Click0(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
private void Btn_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
private void Btn_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
private void Btn_Click3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

correspondingly.

Apparently codes above will not work, because `Btn_ClickTemp` is a string.

Maybe `System.Reflecttion` could help. But I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You can create as many buttons as you want, but you probably want the same click handler, or to choose from a small set of them. Then use the `sender` event argument to work out which button it was.

Comment: @Yichao: your mistake is in thinking you can treat a (runtime) string value like a (compile time) function name.  You can't.  There *ARE*, however, several good alternatives to "dynamically create" buttons and their corresponding event handlers.  
Jeremy Lakeman gave a good suggestion (that's the first thing I'd try).

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn the 'test' method into an eventhandler for the system to use, something like

```
this.btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.test);
```

That way you are passing test as a delegate method to the constructor for System.EventHandler

Then as Jeremy said in a comment on your post you can use the properties of 'sender' to figure out any details about the button if you end up using test for multiple buttons.

One alternative would be to just have each auto-generated button click event trigger the test method - it does add more code, but it allows you to do things like enable/disable buttons differently for the different instances of your button - e.g.

```
private async void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Btn1.Enabled = false;
     Cncl1.Enabled = true;
     Try
     {
         test();
     }
     Catch(Exception ex){}
     Finally
     {
         Btn1.Enabled = true;
         Cncl1.Enabled = false;
     }
}
private async void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Btn2.Enabled = false;
     Cncl2.Enabled = true;
     Try
     {
         test();
     }
     Catch(Exception ex){}
     Finally
     {
         Btn2.Enabled = true;
         Cncl2.Enabled = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. It is helpful, but I don't fully understand. my problem is: I hope to create multiple buttons, with different button onClick function name. And I need to match the name in `btn.Click += Btn_ClickTemp;` with those function names, for example, like you wrote `Btn1_Click`, `Btn2_Click`, ... I don't know how to make it. I changed the question description. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Yichao: your mistake is in thinking you can treat a (runtime) string value like a (compile time) function name. You can't.  Re-read what The Lemon is trying to say, and consider Jeremy Lakeman;s suggestion above.  See also: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189689/Dynamic-Runtime-Delegates-Conversion

Comment: @Yichao that was the first bit of code in my answer, add an event handler pointing to your method - this.btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.test); //where test is the method you are adding